# Pegar informações do banco e adicionar em inputs

Tags: java, html, aplicação-web

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web e estou com dificuldade pra finalizar o CRUD. O sistema ja esta salvando meu objeto pacthpanel, ele possui equipamentos cadastrados a este patch. As informações estão sendo salvas corretamente no banco o que estou precisando é trazer essas informações de equipamento em inputs para que seja possível o usuário editar essas informações;

*Ressaltando que a tela de cadastrar é dinâmica, onde o usuário pode escolher a quantidade de equipamentos que deseja cadastrar, porisso, se ele cadastra 10, na ediçao é pra vim os 10.

Tela de cadastro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tela de editar patch 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu form do patchpanel

```
<div class="row">
<form id="formQuantidade" role="form"
    action="@{Patchpanels.salvarPatchpanel}" method="post">

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <!-- Inicio da primeira coluna -->
        <input type="hidden" name="patchpanel.id" value="${p?.id}" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nome completo:</label> <input type="text"
                name="patchpanel.nome" class="form-control"
                value="${flash['patchpanel.nome'] ? flash['patchpanel.nome'] : p?.nome}">
            <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'patchpanel.nome' /}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>MAC:</label> <input type="text" id="enderecoMac"
                name="patchpanel.mac" class="form-control"
                value="${flash['patchpanel.mac'] ? flash['patchpanel.mac'] : p?.mac}">
            <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'patchpanel.mac' /}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Endereço IP:</label><input type="text" id="ipAddress"
                name="patchpanel.ip" class="form-control"
                value="${flash['patchpanel.ip'] ? flash['patchpanel.ip'] : p?.ip}">
            <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'patchpanel.ip' /}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Torre:</label> <select name="patchpanel.torre.id"
                class="form-control">
                <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'torre.nome' /}</span> #{list
                items:torre, as:'t'}
                <option value="${t.id}">${t.nome}</option> #{/list}
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Status:</label> <select class="form-control"
                name="patchpanel.statusPatch"
                value="${flash['patchpanel.statusEquipamento'] ? flash['patchpanel.statusEquipamento'] : p?.statusEquipamento}">
                <option>Contectado</option>
                <option>Desconectado</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <!-- inicio da segunda coluna -->
        #{ifnot p}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Número de portas:</label> <select id="numporta" type="number"
                name="patchpanel.numPortas" class="form-control"
                value="${flash['patchpanel.numPortas'] ? flash['patchpanel.numPortas'] : p?.numPortas}"
                onchange="geraAlerta(this.value)" required>
                <option></option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>10</option>
            </select> <span class="alert-danger">#{error 'patchpanel.numPortas' /}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="inputs"></div>
        <br> #{/ifnot} 
  #{list items:p, as:'pathcpanel'} 
  #{list items:pathcpanel.portas, as:'porta'}
  <td><label> Equipamento:</label></br><input type="text" class="form-control" name="porta.descricao" value="${porta.descricao}"></td>
  #{/list} 
  #{/list}

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
            value="${p ? 'Alterar' : 'Cadastrar' }"></input>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger"
            onclick="window.location.href='/patchpanels/listagemPatchpanel';">Cancelar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Meu model patch

```
package models;


@Entity
public class Patchpanel extends Model {

@Required
public String nome;
@Required
public String mac;
@Required
@IPv4Address
public String ip;
@Required
public String numPortas;

@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy="patchpanel")
public List<Porta> portas;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="torre_id")
public Torre torre;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Status status;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public StatusEquipamento statusEquipamento;

public Patchpanel() {
    status = Status.ATIVO;
    statusEquipamento = StatusEquipamento.CONECTADO;
}
}
```

Comment: Se você consegue imprimir os dados numa tela você pode colocar esses dados nos inputs pelo atributo `value`.

Comment: Você pode usar o forEach do jstl